# Where can I ask "Do they use seasons in Ecuador?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Discussions below [this answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22479/6031) led to me posting [Are there some places near the equator that are hottest in their winter and some that are hottest in their summer? Is there a map of this?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/22492/6031) see the "cool" answer there! I suggested in my question that for the mid-latitudes summer is happening in January in one hemisphere and in July in the other.

**Question:** In which Stack Exchange site can I ask if Ecuadorians use seasons in everyday speech, rather than when speaking to tourists where they might adjust the reference to match the visitor's hemisphere?

Comment: yikes, what happened here? Some "Where to ask" questions are very well received here in meta, why not this one?

Comment: I don’t know, maybe post on meta about why some are well received and others aren’t?

Comment: Looks like a "too much details" case, i.e. you asked the actual question here instead of sticking to something only general.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 The `site-recommendation` tag says "**Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask**, and the community will help you find the appropriate site." And yet you're telling me the exact opposite.

Comment: I've added the scope tag as [where-to-post is remapped to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/synonyms)

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is specific to one place, and related to this place and tourists, I believe the most fitting site would be [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), which even has [ecuador tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador) already.

Comment: My question explicitly rules out tourists. "...in everyday speech, rather than when speaking to tourists where they might adjust the reference to match the visitor's hemisphere?" Where is "...and related to this place and tourists" coming from?

Answer (score 3):

You could ask on Spanish Language, which has [a few questions tagged Ecuador](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador) already.

Comment: Yes, after checking the help center there I think it might be on-topic if written to be so. *Thanks!*

Comment: Note that the site accepts question about language not about customs so asking whether Ecuadoreans use seasons might well be closed as off-topic.